# onclick alert for html pages not popping up

Tags: javascript, html

How do i ensure that the alert popup would show up when my link is clicked?

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Test');" class="button4" style="margin-top: 10px; font-family: robotoreg;width: 100%;background:#b3c833;">Click <br /><b>Here</b> Now!</a>
```

The above code works however if i enter :

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Congratulations\nYou have completed the quiz!\nClick Next to play more games');" class="button4" style="margin-top: 10px; font-family: robotoreg;width: 100%;background:#b3c833;"></a>
```

The alert popup doesnt show up.

Any ideas why?
Thanks

Comment: I think @userToLazyForName is right. [Your Code Works](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnxrgq6/1/) but your HTML is bad. Inline styles, not closing `</a>`, the use of a `<b>` tag, use of "click Here" (OK, that's not HTML, [but still bad](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/stop-saying-click-here/)). If you are having issues, then something else is the problem, and we need more code. As pasted, your code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, i use both of ur example

jsfiddle.net/9hk6kcuo/

it works.
the 2nd ex not works 'cause you have ' in your js code (you 're). it split ur code into 2

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing your anchor, `<a></a>`, tag.

Change this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Test');" class="button4" style="margin-top: 10px; font-family: robotoreg;width: 100%;background:#b3c833;">Click <br /><b>Here</b> Now!
```

to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Test');" class="button4" style="margin-top: 10px; font-family: robotoreg;width: 100%;background:#b3c833;">Click <br /><b>Here</b> Now!</a>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwjpj335/

Comment: My apologies , the </a> tag is already there i just didn't paste it into the question.

Comment: @User358218 well still, your code works, check my fiddle. What is different?

Comment: Yep the first one is working, the second one isnt if i add a \n in my alert box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/duyaLwo8/2/ I pasted an example code here with spaces and it doesnt seem to work either :/

Comment: @User358218 well you never commented on my Fiddle that shows your code works. Your NEW example doesn't work because you have a single quote in it. [escaping it works](http://jsfiddle.net/duyaLwo8/3/). Your code works. What else can I say.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Oh okay.. noted with thanks. I managed to solve it thanks to your fiddle. :)